# overall scroll bar is not visible, page is not responsive

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, scrollbar, overflow

[The overflow-x scrolbar doesnt work. I mean Its not visible. however the overflow-y scrollbar is visible[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baRPi.png)

[The page is not responsive. what am i doing wrong. I've provided the code and the following images of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUT24.png)

[When the screen size changes the scrollbar doesnt appear.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3d4Mn.png)

Comment: Hi Mohammed, asking questions with only images won't get you a proper answer. We can only guess what is going on as we are unable to test your code. Please post a [reprex] so we can have a look...

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the min-height a value of 100%.